# Could not find gem mysql2 even though it's in the Gemfile and bundle install is in the Dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create and run a Rails app in container (Ruby image). I create the app scaffolding using: `docker-compose.exe run -d web rails new . --force --database=mysql --skip-bundle` and I'm trying to run with: `docker-compose.exe up -d`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` and `rails.dockerfile`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/rails.dockerfile
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes: 
      - .:/var/www
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - 'mysql'
    networks:
      - ddoc-network


  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'SOMETHING'
    networks:
      - ddoc-network


networks:
  ddoc-network:
    driver: bridge
```

rails.dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

MAINTAINER Juliano Nunes

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

ADD Gemfile /var/www/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /var/www/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /var/www

CMD ['rails', 'server', '-b', '0.0.0.0']
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up -d` and check the logs, I get this:

```
[36mweb_1    |[0m /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'mysql2 (< 0.5, >= 0.3.13)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `each'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:200:in `start'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:184:in `resolve'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
[36mweb_1    |[0m     from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:15:in `<main>'
```

Why?

### UPDATE

This seems to be the same or a similar problem: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2103

I'm running this from a Windows host and I don't have any Ruby on Rails development tools on my host machine, so I can't run bundler on local volume before running the container.

Comment: try pre-fixing with `bundle exec` to ensure correct gemsets are picked up

Comment: When I had `CMD ['bundle', 'exec', 'rails', 'server', '-b', '0.0.0.0']` I got "Switch to inspect mode". If I set on `docker-compose.yml` to `command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` I still get it complaining about mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do two things to solve this.

First, run `docker-compose build` (I didn't know I need to run it for some changes on `docker-compose.yml` and `dockerfile`) so the `bundle install` could be executed and I also had to configure http proxy because I'm behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: proxy is the worst to deal with in docker.  if you are behind a proxy your build machine needs the http_proxy/https_proxy added as well as your Dockerfile as an ENV (`ENV http_proxy=http://myproxy.com` if you are puling from any repos.